# How to Run Code in a Loop Asynchronously without Stopping other Code C++

Tags: c++, loops, asynchronous

I was wondering how to run a loop in the background of a C++ program without stopping the main function, something like `setInterval` in JavaScript.
I don't really want to use any libraries for this, as I don't want to complicate the installation in the embedded machine.

Comment: std::thread.....

Comment: But how would you run this in a loop?

Comment: If you're using pre-c++11, then you need to use os-speicific api like pthread or `CreateThread()` on windows.

Comment: you use std::thread to start a new thread that runs the a loop. Google 'std::thread examples' you will see a ton. If you get stuck post what you have tried

Comment: Check the example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

Comment: @JustARandomCoder JS's `setInterval()` is more like a timer than a thread. You specify a timeout, and a function to be called whenever the timer elapses. C++ doesn't have any notion of timers, but there are plenty of platform/3rdparty frameworks/APIs that do. Or, you could just simulate a timer with a looping thread that sleeps on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This should give enough of an example to build from.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void background(std::chrono::milliseconds interval) {
    while (1) {
        // do your task
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(interval);
    }
}

int main() {

    auto interval = std::chrono::milliseconds(500);

    std::thread background_worker(&background, interval);

    // main work

    background_worker.join();
}
```

EDIT: For those without std::thread on POSIX systems:

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *background(void *interval) {    
    unsigned int interval_ms = (*(unsigned int*)interval) * 1000;
    while (1) {
        // do your task
        usleep(interval_ms);
    }
}

int main() {

    unsigned int interval = 500;

    pthread_t background_worker;
    pthread_create(&background_worker, NULL, background, (void*)&interval);

    // main work

    pthread_join(background_worker, NULL);
}
```

Comment: I have an IDE error from this:  
[clang] No member named 'this_thread' in namespace 'std'; did you mean simply 'this_thread'? (fix available).  
vex_thread.h(180, 13): 'this_thread' declared here

Comment: @JustARandomCoder what C++ version are you using?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea; I'm working on an embedded system for a robotics competition, and it uses it's own C++ library and IDE to download to the robot microcontroller. I know for sure that it's above C++ 11, though, because the ```auto``` keyword works.

Comment: It's also giving me this error: ```[clang] No member named 'thread' in namespace 'std'```

Comment: @JustARandomCoder std::thread was added in C++11, so you will have to use something else, most likely `pthread`.  A good reference is [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15492-f07/www/pthreads.html).  I'll update answer too in a bit.

Comment: Wait, I'm really dumb. I forgot to include it!

Comment: Oh good, I just saw your other comments too so was extra confused.  Everything good now?

Comment: It's still giving me the same error: ```std::thread background_worker(&background, interval);```: ```[clang] No member named 'thread' in namespace 'std'```

Comment: @JustARandomCoder edited it to give pthread example

Comment: Thank you! But now I'm realizing that there's a library for this microcontroller that you're supposed to use instead...